# Disable the firefox default image resizing

Tags: jquery, image, firefox, resize

How to Disable the  firefox default image resizing behaviour using jquery.

Comment: What default image resizing behaviour? Detail, please!

Comment: Well if you're talking about the image resizing if you only show an image (like http://www.sudoku-gratuit.fr/illusion-optique/1image-illusion-optique18.jpg for example), you can't add JS to that. You must look at your browser configuration like here http://www.liewcf.com/firefox-2-tip-stop-automatic-image-resizing-2628/

Answer (score 4):

I'm pretty sure you are talking about the automatic image resizing when you open an image which is bigger than your browser window.

That means if you go to `www.blabla.com/verybigimage.jpg` the image is automatically resized by Firefox.
**This behavior can simply not be overwritten** with any kind of jQuery.

The only way to disable that automatic resizing is to go to `about:config` in your Firefox and set `browser.enable_automatic_image_resizing` to `false`.

The only way to have control over these images is by embedding them into some kind of server side code.

Comment: I displayed the image using IFRAME, it is working fine with out using IFRAME.

Comment: why on earth would you display an image with an iFrame? If it's just an image, display it with `<img`

Answer (score 2):

Firefox will only resize an image if you access that image directly, not as part of a page. Which in turns means that if you access the image directly, there is no way to load jQuery to begin with.

So if I understood correctly what you're asking, the short answer is you can't.

---

**EDIT:**

Since you're loading the images in an `iframe`, you can either make sure that the image is small enough to fit inside the `iframe` OR, make sure the `iframe` is large enough so that images inside it are not resized.

However, if your layout doesn't allow this, then your only option would be to write a server-side script which will serve the image wrapped in an `img` tag, like others suggested. Not sure what programming language you're using, but in PHP you could do it like:

```
<?php
if(isset($_GET['img'])) {
    echo '<img src="path/to/your/images/folder/'.$_GET['img'].'" />';
} else {
    echo 'Must specify an image';
}
?>
```

Save this as `showimage.php` and then call it like `showimage.php?img=yourimage.jpg`.

Hope this helps.

Comment: hi, thank you for your reply. When i use <img src="" /> image is fine(100%), but the problem is when image is placed in <iframe>, firefox showing zoom icon. How to resolve the issue using jquery/javascript

Answer (score 0):

To get around this, a lot of websites link to a page that does nothing but display the given image, rather than link directly to the image itself.

Alternatively, you can do what [a lot of gallery scripts](http://blueprintds.com/2009/01/20/top-14-jquery-photo-slideshow-gallery-plugins/) do: intercept the click event and display a dynamically generated HTML block that wraps the image.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed this with the following code

```
$("#iframe").contents().find("img").attr('height','');
$("#iframe").contents().find("img").attr('width','');
```

Answer (score 0):

To disable image resizing in firefox i have try following code and it work. Try it may help you.

```
document.designMode = "off";
document.execCommand("enableObjectResizing", null, "false");
```

design mode set off because it does not affect any other functionality like contenteditable.